# How to make multi herf link print in one line?

Tags: php, html, css

I wrote this code:

```
echo '<p> <a href="tran.php?page=A"><img src="tran.png"/></a></p>';
echo '<p><a href="course_list.php?page=A"><img src="courselist.png"/></a></p>';
echo '<p><a href="comp.php?page=A"><img src="comp.png"/></a></p>';
```

but when I run it the icon appear one under the other like this

```
icone 1
icone 2 
icone 3
```

I want the icone appear next each other like this

```
icon 1       icon 2       icon 3
```

How I can do that?

Comment: remove `<p>` (paragraph) tags and eventually take a look at [CSS](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/learning)

Comment: They are on a new line because the <p> is a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), you can use an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) instead for the <p> or use css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

Remove P tag

```
<a href="tran.php?page=A"><img src="tran.png"/></a>
<a href="course_list.php?page=A"><img src="courselist.png"/></a>
<a href="comp.php?page=A"><img src="comp.png"/></a>
```

CSS:

```
a{margin-left:10px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `<p></p>` tags, or use some CSS codes.

```css
p{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<p>first</p>
<p>second</p>
<p>third</p>
```

Or Use this:

```css
p{
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<p>first</p>
<p>second</p>
<p>third</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on all p tags:

```
<p style='display:inline;'> .... rest of code
```

If it works you could either css it on all P tags or if that will mess up the rest of the page just keep it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo '<p>';
    echo '<a href="tran.php?page=A"><img src="tran.png"/></a>';
    echo '<a href="course_list.php?page=A"><img src="courselist.png"/></a>';
    echo '<a href="comp.php?page=A"><img src="comp.png"/></a>';
    echo '</p>';
```